# CDC wonder data set API

Tags: xml, api, request, cdc

Does anyone here have experience with the [CDC Wonder API](https://wonder.cdc.gov/wonder/help/WONDER-API.html)? I'm requesting some data for a project but the documentation is severely lacking.

To be a bit more detailed, I want to request data from the 'Detailed Mortality' dataset and limit the search to one state only. However, there are 3 parameters for the xml setting the state:

- V_D76.V9
- F_D76.V9
- I_D76.V9

I've tried several varieties using e.g. '01' or '01 (Alabama)' but to no avail. Does anyone have some experience here?

The xml I'm sending is:

```
<request-parameters>
<parameter>
<name>B_1</name>
<value>D76.V1-level1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>B_2</name>
<value>D76.V1-level2</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>B_3</name>
<value>D76.V4</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>B_4</name>
<value>*None*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>B_5</name>
<value>*None*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>M_1</name>
<value>D76.M1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>M_2</name>
<value>D76.M2</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>F_D76.V1</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>F_D76.V10</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>F_D76.V27</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>F_D76.V9</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>I_D76.V1</name>
<value>*All* (All Dates)</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>I_D76.V10</name>
<value>*All* (The United States)</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>I_D76.V27</name>
<value>*All* (The United States)</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>I_D76.V9</name>
<value>*All* (The United States)</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_V10_fmode</name>
<value>freg</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_V1_fmode</name>
<value>freg</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_V27_fmode</name>
<value>freg</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_V2_fmode</name>
<value>freg</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_V9_fmode</name>
<value>freg</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_aar</name>
<value>aar_std</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_aar_pop</name>
<value>0000</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_age</name>
<value>D76.V5</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_javascript</name>
<value>on</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_location</name>
<value>D76.V9</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_precision</name>
<value>1</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_rate_per</name>
<value>100000</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_show_totals</name>
<value>false</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_timeout</name>
<value>600</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_title</name>
<value>Test request</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_ucd</name>
<value>D76.V4</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>O_urban</name>
<value>D76.V19</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>VM_D76.M6_D76.V10</name>
<value></value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>VM_D76.M6_D76.V17</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>VM_D76.M6_D76.V1_S</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>VM_D76.M6_D76.V7</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>VM_D76.M6_D76.V8</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V1</name>
<value></value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V10</name>
<value></value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V11</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V12</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V17</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V19</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V2</name>
<value></value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V20</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V21</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V22</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V23</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V24</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V25</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V27</name>
<value></value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V4</name>
<value>GR113-027</value>
<value>GR113-053</value>
<value>GR113-082</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V5</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V51</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V52</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V6</name>
<value>00</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V7</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V8</name>
<value>*All*</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>V_D76.V9</name>
<value></value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>action-Send</name>
<value>Send</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>finder-stage-D76.V1</name>
<value>codeset</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>finder-stage-D76.V2</name>
<value>codeset</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>finder-stage-D76.V27</name>
<value>codeset</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>finder-stage-D76.V9</name>
<value>codeset</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>stage</name>
<value>request</value>
</parameter>
</request-parameters>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml of the whole parameter you re submitting? there is an example here: https://wonder.cdc.gov/wonder/help/API-Examples/D76_Example1-req.xml. Also, you have to include the 'Agreement to abide by data use restrictions' parameter in your request

Comment: Edited the post to include the xml code

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "V_D76.V9" parameter to "01".

You also forgot the "M_3" measure ("Crude Death Rates").
It seems to be somehow mandatory.
Add this parameter, for example right after the "M_2" parameter.

```
<parameter>
    <name>M_3</name>
    <value>D76.M3</value>
</parameter>
```

Check out the [Wonder API Documentation](https://wonder.cdc.gov/wonder/help/WONDER-API.html#API-Examples), on the FAQ section, question 3 for a bit more details.